# How to export org subtree as nested <ul>/<ol> HTML list?

Tags: org-mode, html

I have a section of an org-file where there are only headings with no content within them, each line is a (sub)heading.

```
* heading 1
* heading 2
** heading 2.1
** heading 2.2
*** heading 2.2.1
* heading 3
```

I want to put the point at a subtree, type a command, and have a buffer open up with (or copy to clipboard) that subtree converted to HTML. Not to a whole HTML file with `<html>`, `<body>`, styles, etc., just a short snippet like

```
<ul>
  <li>heading 1</li>
  <li>
    heading 2
    <ul>
      <li>heading 2.1</li>
      <li>
        heading 2.2
        <ul>
          <li>heading 2.2.1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>heading 3</li>
</ul>
```

Basically remove the `*`s and mimic the tree structure in HTML, no need to process anything beyond that like turning `/italics/` into `<em>`s or anything like that.

Is there something ready that does that, or how would I go about doing it in Emacs Lisp?

Comment: It's possible to restrict exporting to a subtree and export nothing but the body, so you could write an export backend that could output an HTML list like this one.